# Limit radius of convergence $ S = \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{(n + 1)!}{8^n} $

Tags: calculus, limits

Here's the problem as given:

Let:

$$ S = \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{(n + 1)!}{8^n} $$

If I use the Ratio Test to determine whether S converges, I need to 
determine:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{a(n + 1)}{a(n)}\right| \hspace{1em} or \hspace{1em} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|a(n + 1) \div a(n) \right|$$

What is the value of this limit?

( ) 0

( ) 1/8

( ) 1

( ) 8

( ) ∞

( ) The limit does not exist.

Using the above answer, we know that S:

( ) converges

( ) diverges

( ) might converge or diverge; the Ratio Test is inconclusive.

### #

Here's my steps:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|a(n + 1) \div a(n) \right| \tag{1}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(n + 1 + 1)!}{8^{(n + 1)}} \div \frac{(n + 1)!}{8^n}\right| \tag{2}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(n + 2)!}{8^{(n + 1)}} \div \frac{(n + 1)!}{8^n}\right| \tag{3}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(n + 2)!}{8^{(n + 1)}} \times \frac{8^n}{(n + 1)!}\right| \tag{4}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|(n + 2)! \times \frac{8^n*8^{-\left(n\:+\:1\right)}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\right| \tag{5}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|(n + 2)! \times \frac{8^n*8^{\left(-n\:-\:1\right)}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\right| \tag{6}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|(n + 2)! \times \frac{8^{\left(n\:-\:n\:-\:1\right)}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\right| \tag{7}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|(n + 2)! \times \frac{8^{\left(-1\right)}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\right| \tag{8}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|(n + 2)! \times \frac{1}{8\left(n+1\right)!}\right| \tag{9}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(n + 2)!}{8\left(n+1\right)!}\right| \tag{10}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(n + 2)*n!}{8\left(n+1\right)*n!}\right| \tag{11}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{(n + 2)}{8\left(n+1\right)}\right| \tag{12}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{n\left(1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)}{8n\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right| \tag{13}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\left(1 + \frac{2}{n}\right)}{8\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right| \tag{14}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\left(1 + \frac{2}{\infty}\right)}{8\left(1+\frac{1}{\infty}\right)}\right| \tag{15}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\left(1 + 0\right)}{8\left(1+0\right)}\right| \tag{16}\\[1em]
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{\left(1\right)}{8\left(1\right)}\right| \tag{17}\\[1em]
\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{1}{8}\right|\right] \tag{18}
\end{align}

Both Wolfram and symbolab evaluate the limit as divergent as does the hinted answer.

For some reason symbolab won't show steps for the process, so I can't see where I'm screwing up, hence the posting here.

Thanks!

Comment: $(n+2)! = (n+2)(n+1)!$

Comment: I was aware that (n+1)! = (n+1)*n!. I assumed that the same would apply for (n+2)! resulting with (n+2)*n!. I verified your (n+2)(n+1)! with wolfram and now I'm uncertain of the generic rule for evaluating (n+x)!. Does this always result in: (n+x)! = (n+x)(n+1)! ... Thanks!

Comment: no, $n!$ is the product of the $n$ integers $1,2,3,...,n$. $(n+x)!$ is the product of the first $(n+x)$ positive integers  $1,2,3,...,n,n+1,n+2,...,n+x$. In general $(n+x)!=(n+x)(n+x-1)!$

Comment: That's the explaination I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\text{Line #11 is incorrect}$. $\text{Its}$ $\infty$. $\text{We have:}$ $\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \left|\dfrac{(n+2)!}{8(n+1)!}\right|=\dfrac{n+2}{8}\to \infty$

Comment: Can you please step me through your process to eliminate the (n+1) factorial. Thanks!

Comment: $(n+2)! = (n+2)(n+1)\dots 2\cdot 1 = (n+2)\cdot (n+1)!\Rightarrow \dfrac{(n+2)!}{(n+1)!} = n+2$

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $(n+1)! = (n+1) \times n! $ so $ \frac{(n+1)!}{n!} = n + 1 $

Comment: I was aware of (n+1)! = (n+1)*n!, in fact that is precisely the operation I applied to the denominator in step 11. I assumed the same operation would apply to (n+2)! = (n+2)*n!. This is wrong so I'm looking for a generic rule for (n+x)!. If it's not (n+x)*n!, unless x=1, would the generic rule be:  (n+x)(n+1)! = (n+x)(n+1)*n!?